# In real time, how long is a single day?

Tags: timber-and-stone

My question is fairly simple; How long does it take in the real world to pass one full in-game 24 hour period in Timber and Stone?

Comment: Seems like you could just play it and time it and find out.

Comment: @james.garriss I haven't actually had a single play session long enough to time a full in-game day yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's 55 minutes according to my clock or "about an hour" according to this video

(17 min 11 sec into video)

Comment: Thanks for this. I watched the video and there's a few other useful things in there. It's a shame people don't put this kind of information into a searchable form;- I could waste my life watching videos about a game I barely have time to play!